# R markdown - Not knitting despite the notebook running without Error

Tags: r, r-markdown

So I am trying to make a R markdown using a package loaded from source.

```
install.packages('/Users/~/Desktop/BPA/rBSEM_0.2.1.tar.gz', repos = NULL, type = 'source')
```

With a clear environment, the code runs successfully. However, when I try to knit the document, I run into several errors.

The first is that "object 'sample_SEM' not found". This stems from this line of code:

```
data(sample_SEM)
```

Where sample_SEM is data encoded into the rBSEM package.

The next problem is that it cannot find the function 'getInputGraph' - which is in the package.

```
inputAdj <- getInputGraph(blockList = blockL,blockGraph = G,varNames=names(sample_SEM))
```

Does anyone have any suggestions? Sorry I couldn't be more specific but I'm not quite sure what is happening here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

have you ran `library(rBSEM)` at the top of your first R chunk? You may have ran `library(rBSEM)` at the console, but if it's not in the first R chunk, it's not being loaded when knitting the document.